# Resolve datatype conflicts with Copy command in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a requirement to load the data from a csv file in ADLS Gen2 to Delta table. I am using the copy for the same. One of the column in the target table 'IS_ACTIVE' is defined as TINYINT. When triggering the below code, it fails with the following error.

```
Failed to merge fields 'IS_ACTIVE' and 'IS_ACTIVE'. Failed to merge incompatible data types ByteType and StringType


COPY INTO metadata.md_config_master
FROM 'abfss://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/table_folder/' 
WITH (CREDENTIAL (AZURE_SAS_TOKEN = '<sas_token_string>')
)
FILEFORMAT = CSV
FILES = ('MD_CONFIG_MASTER.csv')
FORMAT_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema'='true', 'header' = 'true', 'inferSchema'='true')
COPY_OPTIONS ('force' = 'true', 'mergeSchema'= 'true')
```

When I did not use 'inferSchema'='true' option in FORMAT_OPTIONS, it was failing due to data type mismatch for a integer column also.  when i used 'inferSchema'='true' then this error disappeared.
But still have issue with TINYINT column conversion.
When I create the target table with all string columns, then the command is successful.

Is there a way to make this code run? I did not define ByteType at all in my target table. May be it is considering TINYINT as ByteType. I am not so sure.

Note: I can actually read the ADLS file and create a pandas Dataframe and convert this to spark dataframe and load the data to target table. But that is not what I am looking for. I want this copy command to work. Hence looking for a solution specifically for this COPY command.

Sample Schema:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metadata.MD_CONFIG_MASTER(

```
CONFIG_ID   INT, 
CLIENT_NAME STRING,
TARGET_DATABASE STRING,
TARGET_DATABASE_MODULE_NAME STRING,
TARGET_DATABASE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME   STRING,
TARGET_DATABASE_CNX_INFO    STRING,
EXECUTION_PLATFORM  STRING,
IS_ACTIVE TINYINT,
INSERT_DTS  TIMESTAMP
) USING DELTA;
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample schema of your source and target tables?

Comment: Edited the main content. Added the target delta table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when your data has **any string values in that column**.

I reproduced this with sample data. I have given a string value in **Age** column.

[image]

You can see, I got the same error when tried copy into code.

[image]

So, check your data if it has any string values in that column.

When I removed the string value and added the integer value in that column, I am able to copy the data.

[image]

Data successfully copied to delta table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. There is no string in my column. It has integer value only. But the type of the column in target table is tinyint, If I change it to integer, the code works. But it is failing if the target column is tinyint. What is the data type of your AGE column?

Comment: I tried with int for AGE column in target delta table with string in csv of blob. It has given me `Failed to merge fields 'Age' and 'Age'. Failed to merge incompatible data types IntegerType and StringType`. For tinyint It gave the above error.

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can see my AGE column is TINYINT only which resulted same error.

Comment: It is other way around for me. When any column in the target is defined as integer, it works, provided inferSchema=true. otherwise it results in error Failed to merge incompatible data types IntegerType and StringType. Anyways, thanks for your reply Rakesh. My code may break with incompatiable types going forward. I am going with spark implementation where I have the flexibility to change the types before writing it to target table. COPY is not giving the flexibility to do so.